# How to change the background colour of a one particular listboxitem in a listbox in metro app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, listbox, microsoft-metro, listboxitem

i am developing an c#/xaml metro application .

I am having a listbox , in which depending upon on one particular condition i want to change only one listboxitem background colour .

This is how i have tried :-

```
if (lststudents != null)
{
    foreach (StudentClass obj in lststudents)
    {
        if (obj.stutype == "Red House")
        {
///I am unable to typecast to listboxitem, since it is of type student class 
ListBoxItem lstbxbitem = (obj)ListBoxItem;
///
            lstbxbitem.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
}
lstbxbStudents.ItemsSource = lststudents ;
```

Please Note :- i want to change background colour of only some listboxitems depending upon some particular condition.

Please let me know how i can achieve this ??

What are the various alternatives ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you completed the above asked task, if so could you tell me how you did it?? Because i'm also stuck in that same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DataTemplate in your ListBox, then you can create a DataTemplateSelector to style the specific item in you ListBox.

You can refer to these links:

[ItemsControl.ItemTemplate property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate)
[ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector)

Here's a good article:

[Using Dynamic XAML in Windows 8 Store Apps](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/01/08/Using-Dynamic-XAML-in-Windows-8-Store-Apps.aspx)